# Show customer wishlist collection like in category view page

Tags: magento2, product, wishlist, category-view

I want to show the customer wish list products to another customer with the layout like in category view page which include the layered navigation, toolbar option, and navigation page.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: If you are looking for a carousel for this, I guess you can use weltpixle carousel. Using it is pretty straight forward weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html but if you just want to show the related products or something like this, you can create a widget for it and assign it to cms footer link